# Exclude documents from query with duplicate fields value

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Could you help me?
How using mongoengine exclude from queryset documents with fields that have the same value?

Suppose, I have model:

```
class A(Document):
    a = IntField()
    b = IntField()
    c = IntField()
```

documents in db:

```
{'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':1 }
{'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':2 }
{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':1 }
```

query: A.objects()
I get all documents

How can I query to get documents:

```
{'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':1 }
{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':1 }
```

It should exclude documents, if queryset has document with the same values 'a' and 'b' together.
Such document should be included in queryset only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use **aggregate**, something like this:

```
pipe = {"$group": {"_id": {"a": "$a", "b": "$b", "c": "$c"}}}
A.objects.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)
```

Another way is to query all fields excluding `_id`, and then calculate the unique records out from the results.